# How to connect to a WiFi network in Void Linux (CLI)?

Tags: package-management, void-linux

Help! I'm a newbie and the DM stopped working, so I can't connect to my WiFi network and reinstall the package.

```
xbps-install -S gdm

[*] Downloading packages
ERROR: [trans] failed to download `libgdm-42.0_1' signature from `https://repo- 
default.voidlinux.org/current/musl': Transient resolver failure
Transaction failed! see above for errors.
```

How to connect to WiFi in Void Linux without needing any additional packages?

Comment: We need to know which packages you have installed that can help connect you to the internet.  IWD? NetworkManager? What packages do we have to work with?

Answer (score 0):

Void base installation contains wpa_supplicant. Its usage is described in docs, see https://docs.voidlinux.org/config/network/wpa_supplicant.html